# Copy worksheet to another workbook VB in different excel instance

Tags: excel, vb.net

I need to simply copy a worksheet from one workbook to another workBook in different excel instance. I got error ('Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC) at  "inputsht.Copy(After:=chartsheet)" line when using below code, can anyone tell me what is wrong please.(excelWB already defined as public var.)

```
Private Sub ChartInExcelBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ChartInExcelBtn.Click

    Dim excelWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim inputsht As Worksheet
    Dim Chartfile As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim chartworkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim chartsheet As Excel.Worksheet


    excelWB = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(xlfile)
    inputsht = excelWB.Worksheets("input")


    chartworkbook = Chartfile.Workbooks.Add
    chartsheet = chartworkbook.Worksheets.Add

    'inputsht.Copy(After:=chartworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"))
    inputsht.Copy(After:=chartsheet)

    Chartfile.Visible = True


End Sub
```

Comment: `I got error` doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: I got tuppence!

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: @manochehr on what line?

Comment: @Robert Columbia inputsht.Copy(After:=chartsheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in below link: [Copy Worksheet from one instance of Excel to another](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4dd79b4a-ddc3-4948-9bf8-f91858c5d5ab/copy-worksheet-from-one-instance-of-excel-to-another?forum=isvvba)

so I change the code like below and it is working:

```
Private Sub ChartInExcelBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ChartInExcelBtn.Click
    Dim excelWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim inputsht As Worksheet
    Dim Chartfile As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()


    excelWB = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(xlfile)
    inputsht = excelWB.Worksheets("input")
    inputsht.Copy(Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    excelApp.Workbooks(2).SaveAs("c:\test.xlsx")

    Chartfile.Workbooks.Open("c:\test.xlsx", Notify:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    Chartfile.Visible = True
    excelApp.Workbooks(2).Close(SaveChanges:=False)



End Sub
```